# Detach ZF2 event listener during unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, events, zend-framework2

I have an event listener set up in the module (it checks user permissions) in the onBootstrap method:

```
// attach permission listener to route event
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$permissionsListener = $sm->get('MyModule\Listener\Permissions');
$permissionsListener->attach($eventManager);
```

It works OK in the normal application.

For the unit tests, it would be great if I could disable this permission system to easily check that all pages are working correctly without worrying about setting up a fake admin user.

But I don't know how to do it.

In my test, which extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase, I have done something like this:

```
// detach permission listener to route event
$sm = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
$eventManager = $this->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$permissionsListener = $sm->get('MyModule\Listener\Permissions');
$permissionsListener->detach($eventManager);
```

But this doesn't disable the permission system. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried mocking the permission listener? we have similar setup like this in our project. What we did in unit test is to also mock the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such test case you should not use the *real* listener instance from your application, but you should set a *mock*. You can read a lot on how to use mocks in PHP unit-test tutorials. For example **[here](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-4-mock-objects-stub-methods-dependency-injection/#enter-the-mock)**:

> It basically involves replacing the actual object with a fake, or 'mock', object that we fully control, removing all dependencies on outside systems or code that we really have no need to test

```
$className = 'MyModule\Listener\Permissions';
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder($className)->getMock();
```

Now you can also use the `$mock` to set values you want to use during the test.